# NHibernate Projections.Cast to custom type

Tags: c#, nhibernate, type-conversion, projection

My quantity column is an int. I want to use Like on it then i try to conver its type to string.

To do this i use:

```
 Expression.Like(
 Projections.Cast( NHibernateUtil.String,
 Projections.Property<ErrorSummaryEntity>(x => x.Quantity)),
 searchValue, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

Its almost works. It generate sql like this.

```
 cast( this_.ILOSC as NVARCHAR2(255)) like :p1
```

Problem here is **N**VARCHAR. I need to get VARCHAR instead.

How can i get this?`cast( this_.ILOSC as VARCHAR2(255)) like :p1`

Second question that might help is:
If i have mapping like this:

`Map(x => x.Quantity)
.Column("ILOSC")`

Thats why i use lambda to work on this column.
Is possible to retrieve maped column name?

`var colName = //some action to return "ILOSC"`

`Projections.Property<ErrorSummaryEntity>(x => x.Quantity)` gives me "Quantity". How can i get "ILOSC"?

If i get this column name i can use `Expression.Sql().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just instead of `NHibernateUtil.String` we have to use: **`NHibernateUtil.AnsiString`**

```
Expression.Like(
    // Projections.Cast( NHibernateUtil.String,
    Projections.Cast( NHibernateUtil.AnsiString,
    Projections.Property<ErrorSummaryEntity>(x => x.Quantity)),
        searchValue, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

See: [5.2.2. Basic value types](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-basictypes)